# html include not finding files

Tags: javascript, html

I nne dsome help with ym html include function. It runs fine on live server from VS but once i loaded it on the domain with filezilla it seems the function is struggling to locate the correct file. The function returns "Page not found" meaning it is running but not getting the file. I have added all the correct file derectories being sure to go up a file path were needs be but it seems only some of the include function executes and the rest doesn't.

JS before body

```
<!--INCULE HTML SCRIPT-->
<script>
    function includeHTML() {
      var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
      /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
      z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        elmnt = z[i];
        /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
        file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
        if (file) {
          /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
          xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
              if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
              if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
              /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
              elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
              includeHTML();
            }
          }      
          xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
          xhttp.send();
          /*exit the function:*/
          return;
        }
      }
    };
</script>
<!--END SCRIPT-->
```

JS in body

```
<script>
includeHTML();
</script>
```

eg of code not reading

```
<div class="product__card" w3-include-html="products/card__xr30_up.html"></div>
<div class="product__card" w3-include-html="../products/card__inno-t4_up.html"></div>
<div class="product__card" w3-include-html="../products/card__inno-t5_up.html"></div>
```

eg of code reading

```
<div w3-include-html="../components/footer_up.html"></div>
```

Comment: Have you forgotten a couple of [..] in the first of the three product card? <div class="product__card" w3-include-html="products/card__xr30_up.html"></div>
 should be <div class="product__card" w3-include-html="../products/card__xr30_up.html"></div> maybe?

Comment: This gets asked all the time and is nearly always a case of the path being incorrect. If you show your hierarchy we can help with that.

Comment: this is one of the dangers when you're using relative paths. I should take time to learn about absolute paths and use it instead. Moreover check with the responsible (DevOPS?) if some folders (eg that "products") are accessible from outside.

Comment: hello guys I found the problem it was something small. my file name was 'Products' and I was calling the file 'products'. So I assume the function I am using was case sensitive. Once I fixed it everything worked again. Not even my images were loading if I called the name without being case sensitive.